# Understating the proof of the existence theorem of Poisson integral from Rudin

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-explanation, harmonic-functions, poissons-equation

I have some problem with the understanding of the following theorem from rudin:
**Theorem $11.7$**: If $f \in C(T)$ and if $Hf$ is defined on the closed unit disc $\bar U$ by
$$(Hf)(re^{i\theta})=\begin{cases}f(e^{i\theta})& r=1\\ P[f](re^{i\theta})& 0\le r<1 \end{cases} ,$$
then $Hf \in C(\bar U)$.
Now recall that $T=$Unit circle and $U=$ unit disc and $f\in L^1(T)$ then
$$P[f](re^{i\theta})=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}P_r(\theta -t)f(t)dt$$
where $\displaystyle P_r(t)=\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}r^{|n|}e^{int},~$ for $0\le r<1,~t \in \mathbb R$. Now proof of the above theorem given as:
[image]

Now I am not able to figure out one thing:
$(a)$ How did they get equation in $(5)$ by using $(4)$ for $r \neq 1?$ That is,  how to derive $(Hg)(re^{i\theta})=\displaystyle \sum_{n=-N}^{N} c_nr^{|n|}e^{in\theta}~$ from $~g(e^{i\theta}) = \displaystyle \sum_{n=-N}^{N} c_n e^{in\theta}~$ and using $(1)?$

Can you please help me to understand this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The proof of $Hg \in C(\overline U)$, from (4) onwards, is only for a trigonometric polynomial (i.e. a finite linear combination of the functions $e^{in\theta}$). At the end of the proof Rudin shows that this is true for every $f \in C(\overline U)$

Comment: Sir I got why $Hg \in C(\bar U)$, but I am not able to find the trigonometric sum equation in $(5)$ from $(4)$ and $(1)$. That is, how to derive $(Hg)(re^{i\theta})=\displaystyle \sum_{n=-N}^{N} c_nr^{|n|}e^{in\theta}$ from $g(e^{i\theta}) = \displaystyle \sum_{n=-N}^{N} c_n e^{in\theta}$

Comment: Compute $P[f](r e^{i\theta})$ when $f$ has the form $e^{in\theta}$ for some integer $n$. This is easy from the definition of $P_r(t)$.  Now take a finite linear combination of such $f$'s to write down  $Hg(re^{i\theta})$. That gives you (5). @abcdmath

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I had made wrong answer previously(, which is deleted now).
I was also just reading this part of the book today, and got confused.

Here is the correct answer.

The equation in the section 11.6 of the book, which is also referenced in 11.8, has an error.

$P[f](re^{i\theta})=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}P_r(\theta -t)f(t)dt$

The $..\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}...f(t)dt$  part of the equation is wrong. The domain of $f$ is not $[{-\pi}, {\pi}]$.

$f\in L^1(T)$. Hence,  $f:T \to \mathbb{C}$,
The domain of $f$ is T = {$e^{it}$ | $t\in \mathbb{R}$ }, which is the unit circle on the complex plane.

Hence, the correct equation is this.

$P[f](re^{i\theta})=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}P_r(\theta -t)f(e^{it})dt$

Now let, $g(e^{it}) =\displaystyle \sum_{m=-N}^{N} c_me^{imt}$

for $0 \le r \lt 1$,

$(Hg)(re^{i\theta})=P[g](re^{i\theta})=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}P_r(\theta -t)g(e^{it})dt$

$=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}P_r(\theta -t)\displaystyle \sum_{m=-N}^{N} c_me^{imt}dt$

$=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\displaystyle \sum_{m=-N}^{N} c_me^{imt}P_r(\theta -t)dt$

$=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\displaystyle \sum_{m=-N}^{N} c_me^{imt}\displaystyle \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} r^{|n|}e^{in(\theta - t)}dt$

$=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\displaystyle \sum_{m=-N}^{N} c_m  \displaystyle \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}r^{|n|}e^{in\theta + i(m-n)t) }dt$

$=\frac{1}{2\pi} \displaystyle \sum_{m=-N}^{N} c_m \displaystyle \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} r^{|n|}e^{in\theta} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{i(m-n)t }dt$

$=\frac{1}{2\pi} \displaystyle \sum_{m=-N}^{N} c_m r^{|m|}e^{im\theta} \bullet {2\pi}$

$=\displaystyle \sum_{m=-N}^{N} c_m r^{|m|}e^{im\theta}$